# Bib number recognition using Keras

Tags: cnn

I want to implement a racing bib number recognition application (for study purposes) using Keras API. I can manage training a CNN model to detect different numbers but how to localize only specific regions from the image and make sure that this region is a bib number?

Steps for this task:

1. Digit localizer - ?
2. Digit recognizer - trained CNN model using MNIST dataset.

What solution would be the best choice for localizing only specific regions? Should I use Faster R-CNN, YOLO Framework, Semantic Segmentation or smth else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**We can break down the task into two parts.**

In the first part, our aim will be to localize regions where the bibs could be found. This is an object detection task, so you can use YOLO, Faster RCNN etc. YOLO could be a better choice as it is fast and efficient. We don't need semantic segmentation here. A number of GitHub repositories are available which enable to train a custom dataset for detecting bibs in images.

In the second part, as mentioned in the question, a CNN trained on MNIST will not be enough. We will need an OCR ( Optical Character Recognition ) which would get the text ( number ) from the image.

> The localizer will produce bounding box coordinates. The image will be
>   then cropped by those coordinates. This cropped image could be passed
>   into an OCR engine and finally, you will get the number present on the
>   bib.

For training YOLO on a custom dataset, see [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/).

For an OCR engine, see [here](https://missinglink.ai/guides/tensorflow/building-tensorflow-ocr-systems-key-approaches-and-tutorials/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few other ways than what [Shubham](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/62356/29575) suggested, with probably a lower development time.

#### Option 1: EAST & OCR

Instead of using Object recognition, you can use the [EAST algorithm](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/) for scene text localization, and then OCR it to recognize the bib number. EAST is quite robust, so this will probably not be very noisy. You will need a bit of [preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935983/preprocessing-image-for-tesseract-ocr-with-opencv) before carrying out OCR. For OCR, you can use [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

#### Option 2: Number plate recognition

Your problem is very close to [recognizing number plates](http://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/), which is a well-studied problem at this point.

#### Option 3: Off the shelf Scene text detection

[DeepSceneTextReader](https://github.com/dafanghe/DeepSceneTextReader)